# Google cloud talent: jobs do not appear in search but appear in list

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-talent-solution

So I've put job offers into google cloud talent, and after they all appear in the list, I try to do a search on them with no criterias (which should give me the same results I guess) but it doesn't. Shortly after the insertion, i have 0 to 2 results missing, but after a couple of hours, there are now 45 results missing from the search out of 220.
The jobs that were missing changed at first, but now it's rather stable and it's the same list of 45 every time.

Entities are created correctly, it seems like there's no problem with authentication either, the project id, company id and tenant id are ok too.

I've tried comparing the two lists, looking for clues in their potential differences, especially looking at the publish time, expire time and visibility since that would be the most obvious reasons they don't come up in the search.

I've simplified the code but that's pretty much it.

```
$jobServiceClient = new JobServiceClient();
$search= $jobServiceClient->searchJobs($formattedParent, $requestMetadata);

foreach ($search->getIterator() as $element) {
    $ids[] = $element->getJob()->getRequisitionId();
}

count($ids); // => 175 results

$list= $jobServiceClient->listJobs($formattedParent, $filter);

foreach ($list->getIterator() as $element) {
    $ids[] = $element->getRequisitionId();
}

count($ids); // => 220 results
```

Any idea of what could cause that?